# How can I get the doors in the Awake but also in the Editor script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The mono script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    // The global state
    [SerializeField] private bool _globalLockState;

    // During runtime use a property instead
    public bool GlobalLockState
    {
        get { return _globalLockState; }
        set
        {
            _globalLockState = value;

            // apply it to all doors
            foreach (var door in Doors)
            {
                // now you would need it public again
                // or use the public property you had there
                door.doorLockState = _globalLockState;
            }
        }
    }

    public void GetDoors()
    {
        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        Doors = new HoriDoorManager[doors.Length].ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
        {
            Doors[i] = doors[i].GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>();
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        GetDoors();
    }
}
```

GetDoors will work only when running the game.

But I want it to be working also in the editor to get the doors first time and each time if I add/remove a door :

How can I implement logic the GetDoors with the editor script too ?

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DoorsLockManager))]
public class DoorsLockManagerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _doors;
    private SerializedProperty _globalLockState;

    private bool shouldOverwrite;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _doors = serializedObject.FindProperty("Doors");
        _globalLockState = serializedObject.FindProperty("_globalLockState");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        serializedObject.Update();

        shouldOverwrite = false;

        // Begin a change check here
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_globalLockState);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            // overwrite only once if changed
            shouldOverwrite = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _doors.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var door = _doors.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            // if door == null the script itself has an error since it can't even find the SerializedProperty
            if (door == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get door property", target);
                return;
            }

            if (door.objectReferenceValue == null) continue;

            var serializedDoor = new SerializedObject(door.objectReferenceValue);

            var lockState = serializedDoor.FindProperty("doorLockState");

            serializedDoor.Update();

            if (lockState == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get lockState property", target);
                return;
            }

            // HERE OVERWRITE
            if (shouldOverwrite)
            {
                lockState.boolValue = _globalLockState.boolValue;
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(lockState, new GUIContent("Door " + i + " Lockstate"));
            }

            serializedDoor.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

I found how to do it. In the editor script in the OnInspectorGUI I added this :

```
DoorsLockManager dlm = (DoorsLockManager)target;
dlm.GetDoors();
```

Like that :

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        serializedObject.Update();

        shouldOverwrite = false;

        DoorsLockManager dlm = (DoorsLockManager)target;
        dlm.GetDoors();
```

The question if it's good that it's calling GetDoors all the time in the OnInspectorGUI ?

Comment: Found how to do it. But The question if it's good that it's calling GetDoors all the time in the OnInspectorGUI ? Edited my question with what I did and it's working fine but not sure if calling GetDoors in the OnInspectorGUI is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to do this repeatedly since it is quite expensive.

Additionally mixing the direct access into the editor script is also bad. This causes all sort of troubles with marking dirty and handle undo/redo. This change might be lost after you close and reopen your project in Unity.

If you want it in the editor script you should always go through [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html)!

---

Actually you don't need any editor script for this.

Simply use e.g. [`ContextMenu`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenu.html)

```
[ContextMenu(nameof(GetDoors))]
public void GetDoors()
{
    var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
    Doors = new HoriDoorManager[doors.Length].ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
    {
        Doors[i] = doors[i].GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply go to your component's Inspector, open the context menu and hit `GetDoors`.